# Find decomposition as stated in Weierstrass preparation theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the decomposition $f = h \cdot g$ as stated in the Weierstraß preparation theorem of the function
$f: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, (z_1,z_2) \mapsto z_1^3z_2 + z_1^2z_2^2 + z_1 (z_2^3 + z_2) + z_2^2$.
I don't know how to handle the $z_2$ in the $z_1^3z_2$-part, do you have any hints for me?

**Edit:** In the version of the theorem I use, the Weierstraß polynomial f is of the form $z_1^d+z_1^{p-1} \alpha_1(z_2)+...+\alpha_d(z_2)$.

Comment: The statement of the theorem in Griffiths and Harris has the extra condition that $f$ cannot be identically zero on the $z_1$-axis, which is not the case here. For instance, $f=z_1z_2$ is not a product of a Weierstrass polynomial in $z_1$ with a polynomial which does not vanish at the origin.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I forgot to mention that in our version of the theorem we want the Weierstraß polynomial to be dependt of the $z_1$-coordinate. I've added that in the original post.